# Banned IP address is still able to access the site

Tags: 7, users

I've blocked the IP address at admin/config/people/ip-blocking and I can see it also in the flood control logs as a blocked IP, but the IP is still accessing the site and I can see errors in the watchdog with their IP address after the block...

I'm at a complete loss as to how this could be... google and SE search has brought nothing. Why isn't Drupal blocking this IP?

Edit: I tested it with a firend's IP and it's not blocking him either, so I guess my IP blocking is not working at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my host has me on a load balancer so the IP was masked by the load balancer. I had to look at the values inside the `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` variable instead of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

See more info here too: https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip/issues/1820048